# Прогресс загрузки файлов через сессии

Tags: php

Привет.
У меня PHP Version 5.4.7.
php.ini

```
session.upload_progress.prefix = "upload_progress_" 
session.upload_progress.name = "PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" 
session.upload_progress.freq =  "1%" 
session.upload_progress.min_freq = "1" 
session.upload_progress.enabled = On 
session.upload_progress.cleanup = On
```

помогите заделать прогресс

```
<form id="upload" action="up.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="dupload" />
    <input id="file1" type="file" name="file1" />
    <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

        <script>

   $('#upload').submit(function () {
    interval_id = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "up.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data=='finish'){
                    clearInterval(interval_id);
                }
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});

            </script>
```

up.php

```
session_start();

$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . 'dupload';

if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])){
    $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
    $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
    echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
}
else {
    echo 'finish';
   // var_dump($_SESSION);
   // var_dump($_FILES);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я делал через jquery.form. Так намного проще.

```
$('#photo-form form').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#progress div').width('0%');
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        $('#progress div').width(percentComplete + '%');
    },
    success: function() {
        $('#progress').remove();
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        $'<img src="' + data.responseJSON.thumb + '" />').appendTo('#photo');
    }
});
```

Comment: Меня интересует здесь только серверная сторона и передача их AJAX.То что Вы предложили - смена интерфейса в зависимости от полученных данных.Это уже конечный этап .,Но благодарен за труд

Comment: При таком способе серверная часть не нужна.